# Timeout during SET SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON with large table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the temporal functionality on quite a large table with 18 million records. For GDPR compliancy I have implemented a way to turn versioning off, delete the records related to the customer that wants to protect his privacy and turn versioning back on. This obviously wouldn't be necessary if deleting records were allowed in a history table. I can see why they didn't allow it, though I don't understand why an option to allow it wasn't implemented.

Turning versioning back on poses the problem. It takes a lot longer than expected, leading to timeouts. Seemingly directly correlated with the amount of records in the temporal table. It takes more than 30 seconds to turn versioning back on and this table is only expected to grow. Is there a solution to this problem other than increasing the timeout?

Comment: I think I remember seeing that the latest build adds this capability.

Comment: @theMayer Would it be possible to provide a source for this please? :)

Comment: I was looking but I couldn’t find the article I was reading. It was a MS article. I was researching the performance of SQL temporal tables when I stumbled across it.

Comment: The article was [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations?view=sql-server-2017). The section is where it talks about CASCADE DELETE. I re-read the section and it is not the same as what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-2017)

> When an existing history table is specified when enabling
>   SYSTEM_VERSIONING, a data consistency check will be performed across
>   both the current and the history table. **It can be skipped if you
>   specify DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = OFF as an additional parameter**.

This should only be used if you are confident the "after" state is definitely valid. Details of the checks it performs [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-system-consistency-checks?view=sql-server-2017).